# What are the criteria for being eligible to vote in a moderator election?

Tags: discussion, election

Can any member vote, or is there a Reputation and/or other eligibility prerequisite?

I think I've been a member for more than a year, yet I never got an election notification.

Comment: It's all explained on [meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135360/theres-an-election-going-on-whats-happening-and-how-does-it-work) -- except, I think, that elections aren't held annually. Elections are held when needed, and the last one on ELU was in 2014. However, the rep requirement to participate is 150, which it looks like you haven't quite reached yet.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewLeach ... shouldn't that be an answer?

Comment: What determines when an election is 'needed'?

Comment: Almost, but not quite, a duplicate of this: [Will there be a 2014 Community Moderator election?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4781/will-there-be-a-2014-community-moderator-election)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Your question (specifically with regard to regularity) was not addressed in either of the answers to your question. There was an election in 2011, 2012, and then 2014. Why not 2013?

Comment: @CJBS: "in the sense used in the election page, regular does not necessarily mean at regular intervals; rather, it likely means that elections are not unexpected and rare events. – waiwai933" [who was and is a mod] - comment on that question.

Comment: What *are* the criteria... ;-)

Comment: @RJH good point. Fixed.